# Android listview onItemClickListener doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, listener

Please excuse my English, I'm French !

I've got a listview, and I want to display an other activity on click on an item.
But the onItemClickListener seems to doesn't work...
I searched on Google, but but I found nothing.

Here my code:

**The XML listView (custom) :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_advert_list_listview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/background" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/advertBackground"
    android:layout_width="339dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7.5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7.5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_advert_list" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/advertImageLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/advertBackgroundLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/grey" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/advertImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/advertPriceLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/advertImage"
            android:layout_marginTop="-30.5dp"
            android:background="@color/white_50" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/advertPriceText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="@string/Price"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="7dp"
                android:paddingRight="7dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/advertInfosLayout"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/advertImageLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/advertInfosLayoutLayout"
            android:layout_width="225dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/advertImageLayout" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/advertTitleText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/Product_name"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_blue"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/advertSizeText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/advertTitleText"
                android:hint="@string/Product_infos"
                android:textColor="@color/b4b5b6"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/advertBookmarkLayout"
            android:layout_width="74dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/advertInfosLayoutLayout" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/advertBookmarkIcon"
                android:layout_width="26dp"
                android:layout_height="26dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/bookmark" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/advertDistanceLayout"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/advertDistanceIcon"
                android:layout_width="26dp"
                android:layout_height="26dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/distance" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/advertDistanceText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/advertDistanceIcon"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="13 km"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_midark"
                android:textSize="11sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**The Java code :**

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Start new detail activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, AdvertDetailActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        Log.w("AdvertList", "Item clicked");
    }
});
```

Have you got an idea ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Doesn't work in the sense..? What happened..? And what is activity?

Comment: Try adding `android:clickable="true"` to the XML.

Comment: @Cornholio, android:clickable="true" doesn't work any more...

Comment: @sujith, I've already put XML and Java Code, wath code do you want ? ;)

Comment: post some more code... the problem might be somewhere else

Comment: @FlorianMacLanglade your posted xml, is that your list row..?

Comment: @Pragnani Yes it is this xml

Comment: `setFocusable=false` for your button as the button is focusable element

Comment: @FlorianMacLanglade: Sorry, I misunderstood, you shouldn't need to include clickable for a listview at all.

Comment: Check the context, try `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're adding buttons/checkboxes to a ListView row, you should add this to them in the xml:

```
    android:focusable="false"
```

Why? Because you have 2 click zones, the button and the row itself, so you have to put your row as the principal touch zone.

Try that to see if it works.

On the other hand, you have too many ViewGroups (RelativeLayouts) in your xml, which will make the draw process slower. Having only one (and maybe some LinearLayouts if you really need them) should be enough.

Comment: No, it doesn't work... And for your other solution, I can't do it... :/

Comment: I am agrre with @Shyish this many viewGroups are really horrible for device to render and if you more then 50 rows your app may crash due to lack of memory also. Try using ViewHierarchy Toolto reduce it.